# Build of Android System is failing

Tags: android, linux, android-source

Regarding building the android project (Android itself, not an app), I attempted to use the following commands:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
lunch command
make -j4
```

This ran nicely, but due to shutdown the build stopped in between. But I tried running the make command again. It is stopping at this line:

**build/core/base_rule.mk:141: somepath:local_built_module and local       installed module must not be defined by component makefiles**

I even tried running it, using make clean command. But didnt work. Can someone please tell me how can i succeed in this.

Comment: Are you trying to build an Android project or the Android OS itself?

Comment: No, its a repo, trying on linux system

Comment: That should be `./build/envsetup.sh`  Which target did you "lunch"?  Which branch did you repo init?  Did it fully sync?  When you say "due to shutdown" did you mean that the build originally failed, or do you mean that your computer shut down and you got this error on attempting to resume?

Comment: Ya it synced properly. The computer got shutdown.

Comment: Also note that you have to do the envsetup and lunch **each time** you open a new terminal or shell, it is not persistent.

Answer (score 6):

You have add to your Android.mk

include $(CLEAR_VARS)⏎

before each module section.
If you build only one module then add it after LOCAL_PATH := in Android.mk

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!